# Gifts to the poor: why only in the 3rd and 6th year?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, commentaries, maaser-tithes, ki-tavo

The Torah teaches us the foundation of tithes: which tithe during which year. In [Devarim 14:28-29](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.14.28-29?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), it states, concerning the "gifts to the poor":

> At the end of three years thou shalt bring forth in that year, all the tithe of thy produce, and shalt lay it up within thy gates:and the Levite, (because he has no part or inheritance with thee,) and the stranger, and the fatherless, and the widow, who are within thy gates, shall come, and shall eat and be satisfied; that the L-rd thy G-d may bless thee in all the work of thy hand which thou doest.

The Rambam in his Mishneh Torah explains [(Hilchos Matnot Aniyim 6:4)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Gifts_to_the_Poor.6.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> **In the third and sixth years of that cycle**, by contrast, after the first tithe is separated, a different tithe is separated from the remainder and **it is given to the poor**. It is called the tithe for the poor.

Last week, my chavrusa and I were discussing this topic, since it was in last weeks parasha. My chavrusa asked me:

> why are the gifts to the poor only in the 3rd and 6th year?, why not
> immediately in the 1st year?, since poor people are really in need of
> any support of that kind.

Is there any source that explain this? **Why wait until the 3rd year for gifs to the poor? Why not wait until the second, or the fourth year etc.. Why especially the 3rd and 6th year?**

Comment: They just had shmitta

Comment: Thank you. I came across a Sforno that describes this: ויתרם של עניים - after the poor have taken what they want

Comment: @Chatzkel "just", were the gifts to the poor enough to wait for the next shmitta?

Comment: I meant to say that in year 1 they are coming off of shmittah. So yea 1 they had. Remember that they always have leket shikcha and peah

Comment: It still doesn’t answer why we don’t do year 2 and 5 which would make more sense

Comment: And that's why I asked this question :)